# checkbox uncheck using multiple class using jquery?

Tags: jquery, class, checkbox

I have a checkbox whose HTML code is

```
<input class="test1 10" type="checkbox" name="custom_tags_checkbox[]">
```

I want to make checkbox **unchecked** using class, I dont want to use id for some reason.How to do it ?

I am trying it with **hasClass** but not working. Here us what I tried ?

```
jQuery('.test1').hasClass('10').attr('checked',false);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('.test1.10').prop('checked', false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".test1 10").click(function() {
        $(this).attr('checked', false);
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

This can easily done by using jquery

```
$(".test1 10").attr("readonly", true);
```